# Glassfish resources/jndi/jdbc login credential configuration

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm deploying my first Java web service app and just finished solving "Glassfish: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : __pm".  I created the glassfish-resources.xml file and placed it in my web-inf folder per http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/pongegf-1517943.html. (It took me awhile to realize that Netbeans put the file in the wrong place to start with).

Now I'm wondering about distribution in the real world where the login credentials are buried in the WAR file via the glassfish-resources.xml file.  Presumably if I ever need to change the credentials, I would have to rebuild for every server configuration I deploy to since my login credentials will be different between environments.  Since we typically go through 2-3 stages of testing environments before going to production, this seems prone to introducing new errors or changes.  Is there a way to maintain the login credentials in a config file that isn't part of the compiled WAR file or am I missing something more fundamental?

Thank you.

Comment: it will be better if you deploy war file on glassfish directly and then run it.

Comment: Thank  you.  Yes, but if every server has different jdbc login credentials, what are my options short of rebuilding/compiling?

Comment: there are options availbe to get to know what jdbc credentials are required

Comment: options to get to know what configuration the server is using simply you can get to know whether its  oracle/mysql or any other db

Comment: So do you have a sample or know what that code actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would setup a [JDBC connection pool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4335/gibzk/index.html) and use a [JDBC resource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4335/ablih/index.html) to reference it. In the application you configure the JDBC resource used via the persistence.xml.

Something like this, when using the default Glassfish derby database (JDBC resource and connection are already setup for this, only the DB must be started):

```
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
 <persistence-unit name="my_persistence">
     <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
 </persistence-unit>
```

So on all your environments you must ensure the JDBC resource has the same name (if you do not want to change the war file) but the actual config can be different, because it is stored in the Glassfish instance and not in your war file.

Comment: I'd be okay with that except I received an error without having the connection pool defined in the glassfish-resources.xml.  I'll give it another try.  Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I finally solved this using @mszalbach solution.  I realized that I had made my persistence configuration application managed rather than container managed.  After I removed the "java/app:" from java/app:jdbc/myjdbc_resource I was able to remove the glassfish_resource.xml file that contained the configuration that I was trying to avoid changing.  Thank you for your help in pointing me in the right direction.  For anyone needing help understanding the difference look at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments, as you asked @Trebor  for determining `DB` type at `runtime` there is way to go through,visit this[JDBC connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)
also

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html

[getClientInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getClientInfo%28%29)

[Entity Manager IN java](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_dbsetup_sqlconn.html)

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-entitymanager/README.html

this will definitely going to solve your issue .all the best .!